# Using .filter() for React's useState setter within a .forEach() loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, use-state

I need to remove objects from an array stored within **cart**'s state.

This should be done by iterating through the strings stored within **selectedCart**'s array.
For each string for **selectedCart** that matches **cart**'s string (within an object/key), it should remove that entire object.

The code below seems to only remove the object that matches **selectedCart**'s string in last index ONLY.

So if it's

```
const [selectedCart, setSelectedCart] = ['test', 'this', 'data']
const [cart, setCart] = [{name: "this"}, {name: "data"}, {name: "test"}]
```

And each object's key (name) has the value of all these strings... only the string 'data' gets filtered.
If I switch the first and last positions (so 'test' is last), only the string 'test' gets filtered.

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
const [selectedCart, setSelectedCart] = []

selectedCart.forEach(selected => 
      setCart(cart.filter(entry => entry.name !== selected))
    )
```

Edit: For the recommendation on another question regarding .filter(), it seems to only be applicable outside of useState().
When I take a similar approach with vanilla javascript, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Try this `setCart(cart.filter(entry => !selectedCart.includes(entry.name)))` (outside of the `forEach`, don't even loop `selectedCart`)

Comment: @speed-o-soundSonic You are awesome! It works perfectly and cuts out the extra looping which is better all around. I've been trying to get my head around why it doesn't work still, despite being messier.

Comment: You're scheduling a new state change on each iteration, the reason why you only filter out 1 element it's because that's what the last scheduled state change does: "filter cart where entry.name is not equal selected (aka 'test', the last element)"

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { setCart(i) }; try to visualise it like this

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with setting the state multiple times at once.
I think in this case you want to use a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) like so

```js
selectedCart.forEach(selected => 
      setCart(cart => cart.filter(entry => entry.name !== selected))
    )
```

Although speed-o-soundSonic's answer is probably ideal: `setCart(cart.filter(entry => !selectedCart.includes(entry.name)))`

Comment: It appears the functional update aspect was causing my issue, so you are 100% correct.

I agree with speed-o-soundSonic's answer being ideal for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

here I am giving the full solution to your issue with UI.
Please check it out.

```
let cartArr = [...cart];
const selectedCartArr = [...selectedCart];
selectedCartArr.forEach((selected) => {
  cartArr = cartArr.filter((el) => el.name !== selected);
});
setCart(cartArr);
setViewSelectedCart(selectedCartArr);
```

Kindly check my solution here:-https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filter-question1-y17dd?file=/src/App.js:851-961

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    export default function App() {
      const dataArr = [
        { id: 1, name: "item a" },
        { id: 2, name: "item b" },
        { id: 3, name: "item c" },
        { id: 4, name: "item d" },
        { id: 5, name: "item e" }
      ];
      const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
      const [selectedCart, setselectedCart] = useState([]);
      const [viewSelectedCart, setViewSelectedCart] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const data = [...dataArr];
        setCart(data);
      }, []);
    
      const changeHandler = (event) => {
        const _thisName = event.target.dataset.name;
        const selectedCartArr = [...selectedCart];
        selectedCartArr.push(_thisName);
        setselectedCart(selectedCartArr);
      };
    
      const applyHandler = (event) => {
        let cartArr = [...cart];
        const selectedCartArr = [...selectedCart];
        selectedCartArr.forEach((selected) => {
          cartArr = cartArr.filter((el) => el.name !== selected);
        });
        setCart(cartArr);
        setViewSelectedCart(selectedCartArr);
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="cart">
              <h3>Cart</h3>
    
              {cart.map((d) => {
                return (
                  <div key={d.id}>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={d.id}
                      onChange={changeHandler}
                      data-name={d.name}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={d.id}>{d.name}</label>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
            <div className="selectedCart">
              <h3>Selected Cart View</h3>
              <ol>
                {viewSelectedCart.map((el, i) => {
                  return <li key={i}>{el}</li>;
                })}
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="button__wrapper">
            <button className="btn btn-apply" onClick={applyHandler}>
              Apply
            </button>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```